# Bleeding/Seams on AO Bake

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking

The undershadow of the ruffle here is showing through the top. I get a lot of these black lines that show up.

[image: The edge of the ruffle is attached to the shirt below, there is no space gap, but I get this bleeding :]

[image: You can see how smooth the mesh is, no gaps..]

Is there anything I can do to fix this when baking an AO?
(the unwrap on the left is.. ruffles at the top and shirt with shadows below it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have intersecting or non-manifold geometry and the problem are aliased edges. There is no way to bake the AO with anti-aliased intersecting edges, that is not yet supported.

There are 3 option:

- get rid of the intersections (or non-manifold sections)
- bake a much much higher resolution and then downscale the texture
- go over those edges with paintbrush and fix them manually

Comment: Thanks, thats helpful. I think my best bet in this case is to go over with a paintbrush. Cheers!